# Run time error when I try printing the linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string program;
    node *next;
}

bool isEmpty(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&tail, string program)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->program = program;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    tail = temp;

}

void initialize(node *&head, node *&tail, string program)
{
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head, tail, program);
    else
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->program = program;
        temp->next = NULL;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void insert(node *& head, node *& tail, string program, int num)
{
    if (isEmpty(head))
        insertAsFirstElement(head, tail, program);
    else
    {
        string free ("FREE");
        int i = 0;
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            while (head->program.compare(free) != 0)
                head = head->next;
            while (head->program.compare(free) == 0)
            {
                head->program = program;
                tail->next = head;
                tail = head;
                i++;
                if (i == (num-1))
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}


void showList(node *current)
{
    if (isEmpty(current))
        cout << "The list is empty. \n";
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        cout << "The list contains: \n";
        while(current != NULL)
            {
                cout << current->program << " ";
                if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
                    cout << "\n";
                current = current->next;
                i++;
            }
    }
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Menu";
    cout << "\n1. Add program\n";
    cout << "2. Print Memory\n";
    cout << "3. Exit\n";
    node *head = NULL;
    node *tail = NULL;
    int choice;
    string name;
    int memory;
    int numPages;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        initialize(head, tail, "FREE");

    }
    showList(head);
    do
    {
        cout << "choice - ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Program name - ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Program size - ";
            cin >> memory;
            if (memory % 4 == 0)
                numPages = memory / 4;
            else if (memory % 4 != 0)
                numPages = memory / 4 + 1;
            insert(head, tail, name, numPages);
            cout << "Program " << name << " added succesfully.\n";
        case 2:
            showList(head);
        }
    } while (choice!=3);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is in the insert function because when I try printing the linked list after I call the insert function it never stops printing, but I don't understand my mistake.
Also in the switch in the main when insert 2 as choice it only runs case 2, but when I insert 1 as choice it runs both case 1 and case 2.

EDIT: I haven't changed anything and now once I call the insert function the program stops running

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. You can either add cout statements or use a source-level debugger.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm running the program with the local windows debugger for visual studio is that enough?

Comment: @Matteo and what did you find out from using the debugger? Also, what's the error?

Comment: Yes, the VS debugger is a very useful tool when used correctly. The next step is to think up some examples and work out on a piece of paper what you want to happen. Then step through your code to see if it actually does what you want.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't find anything, the debugger doesn't give me any error and now instead of printing an endless linked list once I call the insert function it doesn't do anything else

Comment: @Matteo You don't use debuggers only to show errors. You use them to examine the state of the program. Do any variables contain data that surprises you? Does the program enter any branches that it shouldn't? If you would have watched the flow of execution using the debugger, you may have noticed `case 2` was entered when (we're guessing) it shouldn't have.

Comment: "The error is in the insert function" -- So why do you not fix it?  Are you sincere, or did you simply forget to report the error?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I know that the error is in the insert function because the programs runs as it should for every function except for the insert function, but I don't know what is wrong with it

Comment: The insert does have problems. "insertAsFirstElement()" seems ok, but appears to conflict / duplicates  "initialize()".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `switch` case, you need to add `break;` after `case 1:`

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` statement is missing a `break;` statement. Since there is no `break` statement for case 1, the compiler continues through case 1 and 2, since case 2 follows case 1.

Here is a more clear description from [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm):

> *When the variable being switched on is equal to a case, **the statements following that case will execute until a break statement is reached**.*
>
> When a break statement is reached, the switch terminates, and the flow of control jumps to the next line following the switch statement.
>
> Not every case needs to contain a break. If no break appears, the flow of control will fall through to subsequent cases until a break is reached.

See this code:

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        // ... Add the rest of your code here
        break // <-- this is required so that the switch is termintated after completing the appropriate case instead of continuing on to the next case


    case 2:
        showList(head); // there are no more cases after this, so only this case runs if switch(2) occurs.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The error is in the insert function"

So why do you not fix it?

---

I agree, that your insert function is flawed.  Below I have marked 3 lines that probably contribute to the code's problems.

Key Idea: When inserting the second and subsequent items to a linked list, your code should modify only 'head' or 'tail', never both.

When inserting at the head, the tail should not change. 
When inserting at the tail, the head should not change.

```
                 vv            vv  
void insert(node *& head, node *& tail, string program, int num)
{
   if (isEmpty(head))
       insertAsFirstElement(head, tail, program);
   else
   {
       string free ("FREE");
       int i = 0;
       while (head != NULL)
       {
           while (head->program.compare(free) != 0)
               head = head->next;       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
           while (head->program.compare(free) == 0)
           {
               head->program = program;  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
               tail->next = head;
               tail = head;              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
               i++;
               if (i == (num-1))
                   return;
           }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Is it the same idea if I want to change items already inserted in the linked list?

Comment: Noticed that "initialize()" conflicts or duplicates "insertAsFirstElelement()".  Choose one, or perhaps have one use the other.

Comment: To change an item, I would think you need a 'find()' method to identify which list element to change. Then, depending on your requirements,  you either change the payload (which you have named 'program') of the found element, or remove it, then insert the new payload.  To change the head or tail is simpler, handle it unique from the middle elements.